# How custom validators is auto included into model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Currently, I've created custom email validator for rails model.

**models/concerns/email_validator.rb**

```
class EmailValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    unless value =~ /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/i
      record.errors[attribute] << (options[:message] || "provided format for email is not valid")
    end
  end
end
```

So now I can use it like:

```
validates :email, email: true, uniqueness: true
```

I'm just curious how it's auto included into model? I mean we are not including it explicitly, by using include method.

Comment: `email: true` parameter will lookup and apply the validator named `EmailValidator` automagically (it’s Rails after all.)

Comment: @mudasobwa ok, so it's conventions. But how does he know, where EmailValidator is located and how it's named? Conventions too?

Comment: There could be only one direct accessor of `ActiveModel::EachValidator` named `EmailValidator`, hence the only thing is it should be on the Rails autoloads path.

Comment: Automagic unveiled - https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/validations/validates.rb#L116 which then calls https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/validations/with.rb#L142-L143 For science. @mudoasobwa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything under the `app/` folder is auto-loaded. So, since you've placed it in `models/concerns` and `models` is under `app/`, it is auto-loaded. Once it is auto-loaded, it will be used as the name is inferred from the option name you pass to `validates :email`. You can place it in `app/foo/bar/baz/email_validator.rb` and it will be auto-loaded as well. Move this validator to `lib/email_validator.rb` and this will not work (as long as you have not `require`d the whole `lib/` folder).

Answer (score 2):

Additionally validator classes may be in another namespace and still used within any class.

```
validates :email, :'custom_validators/email' => true

Module CustomValidators
  class EmailValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
    # Code
  end
end
```

[Please refer this link for more info](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html)